# How to know linux usb device file path for UsbDevice instance on android?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, usb, root

I have to connect to usb device on android and the user is expected to select device and allow access to USB, so finally i have [UsbDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html) instance. How can i know it's linux file path (something like "`/dev/bus/usb/002/001`") to pass it to native code.

Will it require android device *rooting*? If yes i can request usb device permission using standard android approach and i believe it grants usb file access to app process. Will it help?

Comment: or the question can be asked as "*how to find usb serial path using any usb device id from UsbDevice*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `getDeviceName()` method